# Vim: how to disable CSV.vim plugin?

Tags: vim, bigdata

I installed this plugin [CSV.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) but it is firing all the time different errors such has E363 with big files (memory limit problems and others). Apparently, a better solution is to use asynchronous NeoVim/nVim with big files but now on I want to get the basic vim back without highlighting alerting all the time with big files. How can I disable this plugin after sourcing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a *filetype plugin*; that means that `ftplugin/csv.vim` gets sourced on each CSV file again. To disable it, there are several options:

- As the plugin defines a completely new filetype, you can just open a file with a different filetype: `:edit +setf\ text myfile.csv`
- To trigger it only on demand, move the script up one directory and invoke with `:runtime csv.vim`
- To turn off the plugin after the fact, switch to a different filetype: `:setf text`

Comment: many thanks for your answer @IngoKarkat. I erased the `csv.vim` from the `ftplugin` folder but I get a highlighting when I open the a `.csv` file. I can desactivate the highlighting with `:setf text`. I then wrote `setf text` in my `.vimrc` file but the highlighting is still present when I open the a `.csv` file. I can I permanently disactivate it?

Comment: @ecjb In addition to `ftplugin/csv.vim`, there's also a syntax script in `syntax/csv.vim`; delete that one as well.

Comment: many thanks! it worked indeed